# give me some help this error in android studio

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

i want make android ble scanner

no problem start this app but i want startscan and push start scan button then turn off this app

this is error code

```
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
D/ViewRootImpl@d967e4a[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 15923
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(java.util.List, android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings, android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.startScan(MainActivity.java:182)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:141)
        at com.example.myapplication.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$mssl4La-mhhX0ttBjD5v7QdktdI.onClick(lambda)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

this is my code in `MainActivity`

```
    //// GUI variables
    // text view for status
    private TextView tv_status_;
    // text view for read
    private TextView tv_read_;
    // button for start scan
    private Button btn_scan_;
    // button for stop connection
    private Button btn_stop_;
    // button for send dataenter code here
    private Button btn_send_;
    // button for show paired devices
    private Button btn_show_;


    // Tag name for Log message
    private final static String TAG="Central";
    // used to identify adding bluetooth names
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT= 1;
    // used to request fine location permission
    private final static int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION= 2;
    // scan period in milliseconds
    private final static int SCAN_PERIOD= 5000;
    // ble adapter
    private BluetoothAdapter ble_adapter_;
    // flag for scanning
    private boolean is_scanning_= false;
    // flag for connection
    private boolean connected_= false;
    // scan results
    private Map<String, BluetoothDevice> scan_results_;
    // scan callback
    private ScanCallback scan_cb_;
    // ble scanner
    private BluetoothLeScanner ble_scanner_;
    // scan handler
    private Handler scan_handler_;


    public final static String MAC_ADDR="18:62:E4:3C:2A:1B";




    //BLE Scan Callback class

    private class BLEScanCallback extends ScanCallback {
        private Map<String, BluetoothDevice> cb_scan_results_;

        //Constructor

        BLEScanCallback(Map<String, BluetoothDevice> _scan_results ){

        }

        public void onScanResult(int _callback_type, ScanResult _result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScanResult");
            addScanResult(_result);

        }

        public void onScanFailed(int _error) {
            Log.e(TAG,"BLE scan failed with code "+_error);
        }

        //add scan result

        private void addScanResult(ScanResult _result) {
            //get scanned device
            BluetoothDevice device = _result.getDevice();
            //get scanned device Mac address
            String device_address = device.getAddress();
            //add the device to the result list
            cb_scan_results_.put(device_address, device);
            //log
            Log.d(TAG, "scan results device: " + device);
            tv_status_.setText("add scanned device: "+ device_address);

        }

    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //// get instances of gui objects
        // status textview
        tv_status_= findViewById( R.id.tv_status );
        // read textview
        tv_read_= findViewById( R.id.tv_read );
        // scan button
        btn_scan_= findViewById( R.id.btn_scan );
        // stop button
        btn_stop_= findViewById( R.id.btn_stop );
        // send button
        btn_send_= findViewById( R.id.btn_send );
        // show button
        btn_show_= findViewById( R.id.btn_show );

        // ble manager
        BluetoothManager ble_manager;
        ble_manager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        // set ble adapter
        ble_adapter_ = ble_manager.getAdapter();

        btn_scan_.setOnClickListener((v) -> {startScan(v); });




    }

    //start scan
    private void startScan(View v) {

        tv_status_.setText("Scanning...");

        // check ble adapter and ble enabled
        if(ble_adapter_ == null || !ble_adapter_.isEnabled()){
            requestEnableBLE();
            tv_status_.setText("Scanning Failed: ble not enabled");
            return;

        }

        //Set scanfilter
        //creat filter list
        List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();

        // create a scan filter with device mac address
        ScanFilter scan_filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(MAC_ADDR).build();

        // add filter to list

        filters.add(scan_filter);

        //// scan settings
        // set low power scan mode
        ScanSettings settings= new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode( ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER ).build();

        // Scan callback
        scan_results_ = new HashMap<>();
        scan_cb_= new BLEScanCallback(scan_results_);

        //now ready to scan
        //start scan
        ble_scanner_.startScan(filters, settings, scan_cb_);
        //set scanning flag
        is_scanning_ = true;


    }





    // Request BLE enable
    private void requestEnableBLE() {
        Intent ble_enable_intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(ble_enable_intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    // Request Fine Location permission
    private void requestLocationPermission() {

        requestPermissions( new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION );

    }




    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //finish app if the BLE is not supported
        if( !getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature( PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE ) ) {
            finish();
        }
    }


}
```

give me some help

Answer (score 0):

You use `ble_scanner_` as  `BluetoothLeScanner` and you init that on global

```
 private BluetoothLeScanner ble_scanner_;
```

But you never call

```
 ble_scanner_ = ble_adapter_.getBluetoothLeScanner();
```

So your `ble_scanner_` is null and give you `NullPointerException`

Add above line into `onCreate` like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //other codes...

    ble_adapter_ = ble_manager.getAdapter();
    ble_scanner_ =  ble_scanner_ = ble_adapter_.getBluetoothLeScanner();

    btn_scan_.setOnClickListener((v) -> {startScan(v); });

}
```

Comment: Thank U for answer. I try it But ble_scanner_ = new BleutoothLeScanner(); this line give me  "BluetoothLeScanner() is not public in android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner can not be accessed from outside package" error. how can i fix it?

Comment: @서영진 check my edited answer

Comment: Thank U. I fix this error. i have a question what reason this error, and how you can fix it ?

Comment: @서영진 when you get NullPointerException error on your code its always means your use something that is null (won't initialize) so you must find it and initialize it. thats all

Comment: i haver one more error this code after fix error.  addScanResult(_result); this line in onScanResult(),  and  cb_scan_results_.put(device_address, device); this line in addScanResult() give me same error. I'm android and java develop starter. give me some help. sorry